# Doing a direct struct read in C from preallocated memory failed

Tags: c, struct

I'm assuming its a pointer issue again, but what I'm trying to do here is have a function search memory to see if an IP address exists, and if it doesn't then a random memory space is reserved for the IP address and zero is returned. the function takes an IP address as a string as the 1st parameter and the second parameter points to the struct. When the main() function is executed, result should equal 0 and result2 should equal 1, but instead, I get crashes, and I think it has to do with the way I'm assigning pointers?

In this fragment...

```
ip=(iprec*)p;
```

I'm trying to set the iprec structure passed into the function (and previously allocated by malloc), but I'm not sure where to add or remove stars from that statement.

Here is the rest of the code.

```
char *shma;

typedef struct{
    unsigned char u;
    unsigned char a[4];
    unsigned int otherdata;
} iprec;

static int loadip(char* remoteip,iprec *ip){
    char *p=shma;
    int v=0;
    char *ep;
    unsigned char a[4];
    sscanf(remoteip,"%d.%d.%d.%d",a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3]);
    int i,n;int sz=5000;
    int szr=sizeof(iprec);
    for (i=3;i<sz;i+=szr){
        ip=(iprec*)p;
        if (ip->u=='Y'){
            for (n=0;n<=4;n++){
                if (a[n]!=ip->a[n]){break;}
            }
            if (n >= 3){v=1;break;}
        }else{
            ep=p;
        }
        p+=szr;
    }
    if (v==0){
        ip=(iprec*)ep;
        for (n=0;n<=3;n++){
            ip->a[n]=a[n];
        }
    }
    return v;
}

int main(){
    char *shma=(char*)malloc(5000); //alloc 5000 bytes for example.
    iprec *x=(iprec*)malloc(sizeof(iprec));
    int result=loadip("127.0.0.1",x);
    int result2=loadip("127.0.0.1",x);
}
```

Comment: 0) `char *shma=(char*)malloc(5000);` set to local variable `shma`

Comment: 1) `ip=(iprec*)p;` unused argument of `ip`

Comment: 2) `sscanf(remoteip,"%d.%d.%d.%d",a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3]);` : `a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3]` are not `int *`, just `char`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Replace

   `sscanf(remoteip,"%d.%d.%d.%d",a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3])`;

With

```
sscanf(remoteip,"%d.%d.%d.%d",&a[0],&a[1],&a[2],&a[3]);
```

`sccanf` needs pointer type arguments.

2. `shma` should be global.

Comment: The reason why I was trying character type arguments is because I want to store the IP's as four chars so that the memory requirement is 4 bytes as opposed to 8 or 16 bytes.

Comment: I missed the sscanf in my answer, but I want to add here that instead of `%d` you should do `%hhd` to ensure that the assignments are to char width data. Using just %d uses natural int size, which can result in incorrect data depending on the endian of the host, and can result in overwriting neighboring data on any machine (and sometimes alignment errors).

Answer (score 2):

I haven't done a full analysis of your code, but here is a source of your crash. At the bottom is a resolution

### Analysis

At the top of your snippet, you have

```
char *shma;
```

This is a file-scope (global) object called shma that has static duration storage. It gets initialized to 0 prior to main() executing.

Then, in main, you have:

```
int main(){
    char *shma=(char*)malloc(5000); //alloc 5000 bytes for example.
```

Here you declare a new object called shma. It has block scope (exists only within the context of main), with automatic storage. You assign to it a pointer from malloc(). Then you call `loadip`.

`loadip` has

```
char *p=shma;
```

Which declares a new object called p with block scope (exists in loadip) with automatic storage. You set it to `shma`. **NOTE** this is assigning the global shma, not the one in `main`, because the one in main only exists within main, and `loadip` is outside of main. The global shma was 0, so now p is also 0 (at least for your first loop).

Then, you do:

```
    ip=(iprec*)p;
```

so, since p was 0, now ip is 0. In the next line:

```
    if (ip->u=='Y'){
```

you are dereferencing `ip` to obtain member `u`. On most systems, this dereference will result in a segmentation fault (or similar memory access violation), because you have essentially dereferenced `NULL` (the 0 address).

### Fix for this issue

Change

```
int main(){
    char *shma=(char*)malloc(5000); //alloc 5000 bytes for example.
```

into

```
int main(){
    shma=(char*)malloc(5000); //alloc 5000 bytes for example.
```

This will result in main assigning to the global `shma` instead of creating a new local one.

Comment: I meant to do it like that. I was rushing the main function.

Answer (score 1):

Its a while since I've done C, but a few thoughts :

```
char *p=shma;
```

but shma has not yet been initialised - and consequently the "ip=(iprec*)p;" means ip will not be a valid value.

```
unsigned char a[4];
sscanf(remoteip,"%d.%d.%d.%d",a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3]);
```

you need the address of the receiving variables (ie. &a[0], &a[1], ...).
Also, since '%d' will write 4 byte integers (the scanf doesn't know it's a char array), better to have "int a[4]"

```
ip=(iprec*)p;
```

But ip is an input parameter - so here you're overwriting (ie. throwing away) whatever value the user supplied in the second argument.

```
if (v==0){
    ip=(iprec*)ep;
```

Even if v=0, it is still possible that ep has not been initialised (eg.if all ip->u == 'Y' but the a-arrays differ on the first or second values)

Comment: This seems to work, but my function is slow. 

`static int loadip(request_rec *r,iprec *cip){
 int v=0;char*p=shma;iprec *ep;
 unsigned int a[4];sscanf(r->connection->remote_ip,"%d.%d.%d.%d",&a[0],&a[1],&a[2],&a[3]);
 dir_config *dir=loadscfg(r->server);
 int i,n;int sz=dir->PSZ,szs=sizeof(iprec);
 for (i=1;i<sz;i+=szs){
 iprec *cip=(iprec*)p;
 if (cip->u=='Y'){
 for (n=0;n<=4;n++){if (a[n]!=(unsigned char)cip->a[n]){break;}}
 if (n >= 3){v=1;break;}
 }else{
 ep=(iprec*)p;
 }
 p+=szs;
 }
 if (v==0){ep->u='Y';for (n=0;n<=3;n++){ep->a[n]=a[n];}}
 return v;
}
`